# Tools to parse .scc closed caption subtitles

Tags: open-source, java, video, media-player, parser

I'm trying to find a tool or library (possibly an open-source tool) to parse or convert .`scc` closed caption subtitle files to a human readable text, say .`srt` or `xml` or any text formats. Is there a strong tool or library to do that?

Previously, I was trying to use `PyCaption` library in Python. But it fails to parse certain .`scc` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This command line tool](https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles) currently converts better .scc files than PyCaption.

```
php subtitles.phar input.scc output.srt
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used CCASDI.exe (Windows Executable) from this page successfully: http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_TOOLS.HTML#ccasdi

And I have also used this JavaScript library: https://github.com/jasonrojas/node-captions

Or you can also use this online tool to edit SCC files: https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/online

I know of other people who have been using the same Python tool you used, but with a small tweak: https://github.com/bdon/pycaption

You added the `Java` tag to your question. Unfortunately, I don't know of any Java tool to read/convert SCC files, but I hope the above helps.